# Why Unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift4.2

I'm trying to make a convenient Binding keyboard to a uiview function. I can't get across this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Twitter.LoginVC handleKeyboard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbf142e970'

```
class KeyboardService {

var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var vc: UIViewController!

func bind(bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, vc: UIViewController) {
    constraint = bottomConstraint
    self.vc = vc
    NotificationService.instance.addKeyboardObservers(onVC: vc, handleKeyboardSelector: #selector(self.handleKeyboard(_:))) // **CRASHES HERE**
}

@objc func handleKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    NotificationService.instance.handleKeyboard(notification: notification, bottomConstraint: constraint, vc: vc)
} 
}
```

Here's my notificationService:

```
class NotificationService {
static let instance  = NotificationService()

func addKeyboardObservers(onVC vc: UIViewController, handleKeyboardSelector: Selector) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(vc, selector: handleKeyboardSelector, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(vc, selector: handleKeyboardSelector, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
}
```

EDIT:

```
class KeyboardService {

var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var vc: UIViewController!

func bind(bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, vc: UIViewController) {
    constraint = bottomConstraint
    self.vc = vc
    NotificationService.instance.addKeyboardObservers(self, handleKeyboardSelector: #selector(self.handleKeyboard(_:)))
}

@objc func handleKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    NotificationService.instance.handleKeyboard(notification: notification, bottomConstraint: constraint, vc: vc)
}
```

}

EDIT 2:

```
class KeyboardService {

var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var vc: UIViewController!

func bind(bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint, vc: UIViewController) {
    constraint = bottomConstraint
    self.vc = vc
    NotificationService.instance.addKeyboardObservers(self, handleKeyboardSelector: #selector(handleKeyboard(_:)))
}

@objc func handleKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    NotificationService.instance.handleKeyboard(notification: notification, bottomConstraint: constraint, vc: vc)
}
}
```

In viewDidLoad() of a vc:

```
KeyboardService().bind(bottomConstraint: loginBtnBackViewBottomConstraint, vc: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sent the selector to `vc`; but it's a `UIViewController` that doesn't actually have a method called `handleKeyboard(_:)`. You should change to this your registering method:

```
func addKeyboardObservers(_ observer: Any, handleKeyboardSelector: Selector) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer, selector: handleKeyboardSelector, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer, selector: handleKeyboardSelector, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

And then when you use it, you'd do:

```
NotificationService.instance.addKeyboardObservers(self, handleKeyboardSelector: #selector(self.handleKeyboard(_:)))
```

As you can see you're now telling to trigger the selector on `self`, because it's actually `self` that has that method.
As a general rule: a selector is sent to an instance, so it's that instance that must have the chosen method.

---

If you really want to send the selector to a `viewController` instance you could create an `extension` that adds the method to every `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController {

    @objc func handleKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Then, on registration do:

```
NotificationService.instance.addKeyboardObservers(onVC: vc, handleKeyboardSelector: #selector(vc.handleKeyboard(_:))) // notice the vc.handleKeyboard instead of self.handleKeyboard
```

---

**EDIT**
Try to retain the keyboard service in the view controller:

```
let keyboardService = KeyboardService()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    keyboardService.bind(bottomConstraint: loginBtnBackViewBottomConstraint, vc: self)
}
```

Comment: no crash anymore but the selector isn't called, see the question again please

Comment: @swiftixcode10 I updated with another solution; can you share the block of code where you call `bind` function?

Comment: The question is how do i get the bottom constraint into the extension selector method.

Comment: If you want to access to specific property maybe you have to create a class that exposes it (or a protocol); however it's strange that the selector isn't called with the first solution, show me where you call the method `bind`

Comment: check now please

Comment: Omg its working now MUCH MUCH THANKS. I just don't understand where the complete issue was

Comment: It's related to ARC (Automatic Reference Counting, the way iOS manage memory); you were using `KeyboardService` as a local variable: local variables gets destroyed when a method ends if they are not "retained"; by storing it as an instance variable, it will live until the whole view controller gets destroyed